# Android InflateException: Binary XML file line #178: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting a Inflate Exception error inflating class fragment

This is the error I am getting InflateException: Binary XML file line #178: Error inflating class fragment

The issue is with the starting line of the fragment

```
   <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4" >
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.08"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_titlebar"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_locationDetails_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_prev" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_mark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_location" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_users"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_users" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_chatting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_chatting" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.92"
    android:background="#e0e0e0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_details"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_details_category"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="ADAM RESTURANT"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#106c61"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_details_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="3222 MAIN ST"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#106c61"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_details_checkin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_checkin"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/location_service"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#6f7179"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4" >
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_details_direction"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_direction"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/location_direction"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#6f7179"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/location_info_panel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show me your manifest and activity where you used this mapFragment..

Comment: How can you manage as much view without ScrollView ?

Answer (score 0):

What is Your minimum sdk and target sdk version? I am not really sure, but the only error I can imagine is, that Your minSDK/targetSDK are not taregting to min API12. If You want to develop with MapFragment, use minimum target API 12, if You want to develop on a lower API, then You have to use SupportMapFragment:

```
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

and include the library. See this for details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html